# Servant always give me a initial value in ReaderT Monad

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm learning Servant and write a simple service. Here's source code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module BigMama where

import           Control.Concurrent
import           Control.Concurrent.STM
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.Reader
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C
import           Data.Char
import qualified Data.Map as M
import           Debug.Trace
import           GHC.Generics
import           Prelude hiding (id)
import           Servant

data MicroService = MicroService
  { name :: String
  , port :: Int
  , id :: Maybe String
  } deriving (Generic)

instance ToJSON MicroService
instance FromJSON MicroService

instance Show MicroService where
  show = C.unpack . encode

type ServiceSet = STM (TVar (M.Map String MicroService))

type LocalHandler = ReaderT ServiceSet IO

defaultServices :: ServiceSet
defaultServices = newTVar $ M.fromList []

type Api =
  "bigmama" :> Get '[JSON] (Maybe MicroService)
  :<|> "bigmama" :> ReqBody '[JSON] MicroService :> Post '[JSON] MicroService

api :: Proxy Api
api = Proxy

serverT :: ServerT Api LocalHandler
serverT = getService
  :<|> registerService

getService :: LocalHandler (Maybe MicroService)
getService = do
  stm <- ask
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    tvar <- stm
    mss <- readTVar tvar
    return $ M.lookup "file" mss

registerService :: MicroService -> LocalHandler MicroService
registerService ms = do
  stm <- ask
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    tvar <- stm
    mss <- readTVar tvar
    let mss' = M.insert (name ms) ms mss
    writeTVar tvar mss'
  return ms

readerToHandler' :: forall a. ServiceSet -> LocalHandler a -> Handler a
readerToHandler' ss r = liftIO $ runReaderT r ss

readerToHandler :: ServiceSet -> (:~>) LocalHandler Handler
readerToHandler ss = Nat (readerToHandler' ss)

server :: Server Api
server = enter (readerToHandler defaultServices) serverT
```

It seems like servant providing a new `defaultServices` for every request. I send POST to create service (name = "file") and can't get the service back on GET request. How to share data among requests on servant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like servant providing a new `defaultServices` for every request.

It is, because your code as written is an `STM` action to do so. Following the logic—

```
defaultServices :: ServiceSet
defaultServices = newTVar ...
```

This (fragmentary) definition crucially does not *run* the `STM` action to produce a new `TVar`. Instead it defines a value (`defaultServices`) which is an `STM` action which can produce `TVar`s. Following where `defaultServices` gets passed to, you use it in your handlers like—

```
getService = do
  stm <- ask
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    tvar <- stm
    ...
```

The action stored in your `Reader` is unchanged from the `defaultServices` value itself, so this code is equivalent to—

```
getService = do
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    tvar <- defaultServices
    ...
```

And by substituting in the definition of `defaultServices`—

```
getService = do
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    tvar <- newTVar ...
    ...
```

This now looks obviously wrong. Instead of `defaultServices` being an action to produce a new `TVar`, it should be that `TVar` itself, right? So on the type level without aliases—

```
type ServiceSet = STM (TVar (M.Map String MicroService)) -- From this
type Services   =      TVar (M.Map String MicroService)  -- To this

defaultServices :: Services
```

Now `defaultServices` represents an actual `TVar`, instead of a method of creating `TVar`s. Writing this may seem tricky if it's your first time because you somehow have to run an `STM` action, but `atomically` just turns that into an `IO` action, and you probably “know” that there is no way to escape `IO`. This actually is *incredibly* common though, and a quick look at the actual [stm documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm) for the functions in play will point you right to the answer.

It turns out that this is one of those exciting times in your life as a Haskell developer that you get to use `unsafePerformIO`. The definition of [`atomically`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-STM.html#v:atomically) spells out pretty much exactly what you have to do.

> Perform a series of STM actions atomically.
>
> You cannot use `atomically` inside an `unsafePerformIO` or
>   `unsafeInterleaveIO`. Any attempt to do so will result in a runtime
>   error. (Reason: allowing this would effectively allow a transaction
>   inside a transaction, depending on exactly when the thunk is
>   evaluated.)
>
> However, see `newTVarIO`, which can be called inside `unsafePerformIO`,
>   and which allows top-level `TVar`s to be allocated.

Now there's one final piece of this puzzle that isn't in the documentation, which is that unless you tell GHC not to inline your top-level value produced using `unsafePerformIO`, you might still end up with sites where you use `defaultServices` having their own unique set of services. E.g., without forbidding inlining this would happen—

```
getService = do
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    mss <- readTVar defaultServices

getService = do
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    mss <- readTVar (unsafePerformIO $ newTVarIO ...)
    ...
```

This is a simple fix though, just add a `NOINLINE` pragma to your definition of `defaultServices`.

```
defaultServices :: Services
defaultServices = unsafePerformIO $ newTVar M.empty
{-# NOINLINE defaultServices #-}
```

---

Now this is a fine solution, and I've happily used it in production code, but there are [some objections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Top_level_mutable_state) to it. Since you're already fine with using a `ReaderT` in your handler monad stack (and the above solution is mostly for people who for some reason are avoiding threading a reference around), you could just create a new `TVar` at program initialization and then pass that in. The briefest sketch of how that would work is below.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  services <- atomically (newTVar M.empty)
  run 8080 $ serve Proxy (server services)

server :: TVar Services -> Server Api
server services = enter (readerToHandler services) serverT

getService :: LocalHandler (Maybe MicroService)
getService = do
  services <- ask
  liftIO . atomically $ do
    mss <- readTVar services
    ...
```